React-Spring Swap Animation Bug
I'm trying a very simple animation to swap two Divs position with @react-spring/web but I can't. It seems partially working but I don't understand why.
It looks like the useSprings hook is not removing the previous node from the DOMs as far as I could guess, but I don't know what to do. Do I have to use other hooks ?
Here's the codesandbox link, https://codesandbox.io/p/sandbox/still-cookies-yf2sky
Comments and helps really appreciated!
  const [coord, setCoord] = useState<{ x: Number; y: number }[]>(initialCoords);

  const [springs, api] = useSprings(2, (i) => ({
    from: {
      x: coord[i].x,
      y: coord[i].y,
    },
  }));

  const box1Ref = useRef<HTMLInputElement | null>(null);
  const box2Ref = useRef<HTMLInputElement | null>(null);

  const swapBoxes = () => {
    let newCoord = [coord[1], coord[0]];

    api.start((i) => {
      return {
        from: { ...coord[i] },
        to: { ...newCoord[i] },
      };
    });

    setCoord(newCoord);
  };

//...
   return
     <div>
        <animated.div style={springs[0]}>
          <div
            style={{ border: "1px solid red", width: "100px", height: "100px" }}
          >
            A
          </div>
        </animated.div>

        <animated.div style={springs[1]}>
          <div
            style={{ border: "1px solid red", width: "100px", height: "100px" }}
          >
            B
          </div>
        </animated.div>
      </div>



Okay i got it now. I missed the CSSProperties position:absolute for each animated.divs.
